# searching some words in a paragraph using mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, search

I am working on a project.I have a paragraph and I have some tags like C#,mysql,.net,ajax etc.I want to check whether my paragraph contains these tags or not and if it contains which one it contains and how many tags matches.Depending on the number of tags matched I have to give a score.I am not getting how to do this i can't use in clause here neither i can use find_in_set().Please help me how should I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's [Full text search](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-full-text-search.aspx) seems to be exactly what you're looking for, although by default it might have some troubles searching for `C#`, because of both the short length and the special character.

Alternatively, you can just use `LIKE`, to search for `paragraph LIKE '%PHP%'`.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work too well.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00d03/18  'mysql' search worked OK but not 'php' ( maybe word was too short?)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html -> "The default minimum value is four characters"

Comment: ya exactly i tried to implement this and i am not getting the desired results.So what should i do now-fulltext search requires atleast 4 character length word

Comment: its neither working for me even if the word i greater than 4 characters

Comment: SELECT * FROM tblquestion t where match(t.answer) against('language') and t.id='1'; I tried this query

Comment: Have you checked the query results? `Match` returns the score you wanted. It is 0 for the first two rows, because there is no match at all. It is a calculated score for the third one. Seems you work just fine when you actually filter out the 0-score rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00d03/24

Comment: But if it's too complex, or just doesn't suit your needs, maybe you can just use `like`.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/340f6/1/0  check this out,i am matching language which exists in 4th para but i am getting relevance 0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49324/discussion-between-rupinder18-and-goleztrol)

Comment: Let's not continue this discussion at all. I think you should read and experiment a little more. 25 minutes is pretty short to learn the ins and outs of a previously unknown feature.

Comment: The issue with `LIKE` is that it doesn't match on word boundaries.  `LIKE 'C'` also matches `C++`, `C#`, and `Clojure`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the REGEXP feature of mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE texts ( 
  paragraph text, 
  FULLTEXT INDEX( paragraph ))
engine = myisam;
INSERT INTO texts ( paragraph ) values
( "this is a very uninteresting paragraph "), 
(  "MySQL can be fun and useful, with or without PHP!"),
(" I have misspelled phpone, but I didn't mean the programming language!");

select paragraph FROM texts
  where paragraph REGEXP( "[[:<:]]php[[:>:]]");
```

It's not as efficient as a FULLTEXT search but may better fit your needs.  Depends.

Comment: i have a table which have different questions,their answers and their tags.Now suppose a user answers question 1 then it sholud match the answer with the tags for that question.So this whole thing is dynamic how should i use regex to solve this

Comment: You'd plug a dynamic variable in place of 'php' when creating the query.  Or use `CONCAT()` and a mysql `@variable`.  Just like any dynamic query.